# PhpStorm how I can execute SQL query in OpenCart 2.3 model?

Tags: php, phpstorm, opencart

I've got an error from PhpStorm:

> Unable to resolve column 'category_id'

Code is from standard model `admin/model/Category.php`

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");
```

Can't execute this query from IDE and get above error. If I will change `" . DB_PREFIX . "` to `oc_` then the query will work and there are no error.

Is there any solution to bypass this error?

P.S. `DB_PREFIX` is defined and PhpStorm shows definition on <kbd>CMD + Click</kbd>

Comment: Please, never use such a query in production. Have a look at prepared statements

Comment: What's your IDE version? it should work for the trivial cases (as per [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26986#focus=Comments-27-2905216.0-0)). Maybe it depends on how `DB_PREFIX` is defined -- not sure as I'm not using such code at all (I always have separate DB so no prefix is needed + using query builder / prepared statements -- can view final SQL during runtime and copy-paste it to improve/debug in a separate tool)

Comment: @NicoHaase, that is not my code. Just paste from Opencart model file for example. So u can reproduce my issue.
 
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/model/catalog/category.php

Line: 272

Comment: @LazyOne PhpStorm 2020.2 . DB_PREFIX defined in config.php and is visible for IDE, when i press CMD+click on DB_PREFIX  IDE shows me config.php file.

Comment: @AlxJZX Cannot say anything here. In theory it supposed to work (as per that dev comment). Consider filling a ticket at PhpStorm Issue Tracker -- maybe devs can say what is wrong here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI